# Pick out k elements as from a text file

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

I am new to UNIX and am trying to learn basic level text processing in UNIX so maybe this question may seem very basic but I would really appreciate any guidance.

I have a txt file "data.txt" as below

```
A 1 
B 2 
C 9 
D 1 
A 5 
B 3 
C 9 
A 6 
C 7 
A 5 
C 1
```

for which I was able to piece together a code inside a shell script "script.sh" (with a lot of help) as below

```
#!/bin/bash

cat | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=" "}!(($1,$2)in c){c[$1,$2]=1;r[$1]=r[$1] OFS $2} END{for(i in r){print i r[i]}}'
```

This script is called on the text file as below

```
cat data.txt | ./script.sh 7
```

to get it to print the format below:

```
A 1 5 6 5
B 2 3
C 9 4 7 1
D 1
```

My shell script will also take an argument k (=7 say)

In this case, my script should sample 1 element from each box(A,B,C,D) until have a total of 7 elements sampled. This will be like follows: First pick 1 from A, then 2 from B,9 from C, 1 from D, 5 from A,3 from B, 4 from C and display

```
A 1 5
B 2 3
C 9 4
D 1
```

If instead I had k = 9 as my input, then my output should be

```
A 1 5 6
B 2 3
C 9 4 7
D 1
```

Thank you in advance. Request you to please guide me from the awk pipe``

Comment: Does the output *need* to be in that specific format? Having the `A`, `B` etc on separate lines makes everything much harder than it needs to be. Would having `A B C D` as a header on one line and their values as columns below them be acceptable?

Comment: unfortunately the specifications are fixed at separate lines:(